# The trash launcher opens an Internet browser

Tags: 12.04, launcher, trash

I just realized my Trash icon is launching Chrome instead of the trash. What can I do to fix it? I already tried creating a `trash.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` but Unity seems to ignore it. `nautilus trash:///` does work.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting/uninstalling chrome? I think the Dash+Trash icons are encoded into Unity, so otherwise it is likely a bug.

Comment: Now it just opens another browser instead of Chrome. I can't delete uninstall my browsers like this; there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying creating trash.desktop in `/usr/share/applications/`

The following is your standard .desktop file.

[image]

Once the trash.desktop file has been created. Restart Ubuntu and search your previously given "Name=" value from the Unity Launcher.

[image]

If you would like the Icon in the Launcher, simply click & drag from your search results icon to your Launcher.

Comment: Rebooting fixed it. Ubuntu acts up sometimes...